# Explanation needed for min heap

Tags: c++

I understand the basic working of a min-heap and the following is it's implementation in Robert Sedgewick's book:

```
    template <class Item>
class PQ 
  {
    private:
      Item *pq; 
      int N;
    public:
      PQ(int maxN)
        { pq = new Item[maxN]; N = 0; }
      int empty() const
        { return N == 0; }
      void insert(Item item)
        { pq[N++] = item; }
      Item getmax()
        { int max = 0;
          for (int j = 1; j < N; j++)
            if (pq[max] < pq[j]) max = j;
          exch(pq[max], pq[N-1]);  
          return pq[--N];
        }
  };
```

What I fail to understand is these two statments in the getMax function:

```
          exch(pq[max], pq[N-1]);  
          return pq[--N];
```

Why do we need to swap the max element with the element in the second last inserted element?

Answer (score 0):

He's swapping the max element to the end and then "popping" it; by reducing the "size" variable (N), he's essentially making the last element (now the max) element unreachable, and it will be overwritten the next time an element is inserted.